# How to call ajax only once in Angular and Rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There are code:

```
<button (click)="getData()">click<button>

getData(){
  this.http.get('/data.json').subscribe(data => consloe.log(data));
}
```

or use **post**

```
 <button (click)="setData(data)">click<button>
    getData(){
      this.http.post('/data',{data}).subscribe(res =>consloe.log(res));
    }
```

When I click button many time continuously, it will send many time http requests. How I avoid it?

Comment: What about saving it into `localstorage` if it does not exist, if exists you will return data without calling `ajax`?

Answer (score 5):

Get the data once, for example in `ngOnInit()` method, and `shareReplay(1)` it to cache the result.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.myData =  this.http.get('/data.json').shareReplay(1);
}
```

Now subscribe the resulted observable in your button action method:

```
 getData(){
     this.myData.subscribe(data => consloe.log(data));
    }
```

The above technique will connect the server only once no matter how many times you click the button.

Comment: If you use post, and want to avoid multiple button clicks, you may use debounceTime(). For example fromEvent(button, 'click').debounceTime(1000).subscribe()

Comment: share() is okay, but if you have a scenario where you have late subscribers then it won't do the trick. shareReplay(1) is more useful, as it means that late subscribers will get the latest value that was returned from this ajax request.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: check `exhaustMap` ..can be used in this scenario